# Implementing Maximum Likelihood in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtergvvy9mfqkfd/data.xlsx).

I wish to apply maximum likelihood estimation with the following likelihood function:

[image]

From the dataset file, I have a column vector of three variables, rho, (s_x*)^2, and T. There are in total N = 3295 observations. I would like to maximize the above likelihood function with respect to two variables: mu and sigma^2.

By logging the above likelihood, we have the following log likelihood:

[image]

How can I find the MLE of mu and sigma^2? I have tried the following, but I am not confident if it is right.

Assume I imported the data into R with names `rho`, `s.sq` and `T`, then the following is my code:

```
####################################

N = 3295

negloglike.f<-function(theta){

  mu<-theta[1]
  sigsq<-theta[2]

  negloglike<- 0
  negloglike<- -(-N/2*log(2*pi) - sum(1/2*log(sigsq+4/(s.sq*T))+1/(2*(sigsq+4/(s.sq*T)))*(rho-mu)^2))  

  negloglike
}

## optimisation  ##
MLE_obj<-optim(c(30,500),negloglike.f,method="BFGS", hessian=TRUE, control = list(maxit = 30000))

MLE_obj

#################################
```

I am worried that my code isn't right, or this isn't the right approach because sometimes I get warning messages such as:

```
Warning message:
In log(sigsq + 4/(s.sq * T)) : NaNs produced
```

So is my code correct? Or is there another way to find the MLE?

Comment: That error message is because you're trying to take the log of a negative number. Check to see that your data is consistent with the distribution you're trying to fit. You may also be able to reparametrise the likelihood to avoid numerical problems.

Comment: @Hong Ooi, That's what I thought as well, however I checked the data for s.sq and T, there are no negative values for either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, and delivers the following results:

```
$par
[1]  10.67069 110.65132

$value
[1] 15960.24

$counts
function gradient 
      51       38 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$hessian
           [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 17.5756300 -0.28990189
[2,] -0.2899019  0.02188517
```

You probably made a mistake reading in the data. Notice that the variable `s.sq` is called `s_sq` in the excel table.
I read the data using `read.csv` with options:  `sep=";", dec=","`